# find_package() errors during installing package via pip

Tags: python, pip

I'm tring to install **django-dbsettings** with pip but it causes the following error:

```
Downloading django-dbsettings-0.7.4.tar.gz
Running setup.py egg_info for package django-dbsettings
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 16, in <module>
  File "/path/virtualenv/build/django-dbsettings/setup.py", line 23, in  <module>
    packages=find_packages(include=['dbsettings']),
TypeError: find_packages() got an unexpected keyword argument 'include'
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "<string>", line 16, in <module>

File "/path/virtualenv/build/django-dbsettings/setup.py", line 23, in <module>

packages=find_packages(include=['dbsettings']),

TypeError: find_packages() got an unexpected keyword argument 'include'
```

Also I'm using pip 1.0 and python 2.7.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

There is no `include` keyword in `find_packages()` using older versions of setuptools, you need to upgrade:

```
pip install -U setuptools
```

I would also update pip.

Comment: This solution is valid also for pandas 0.23.1 installation similar issue. Thanks.